# How to unlock user xelsysadm?

Tags: identity, identity-management, oim, identitymanager

While logging into OIM the xelsysadm  account got locked any idea how to unlock xelsysadm account?

Answer (score 3):

One of the easiest way is to :

```
    update usr set usr_login_attempts_ctr=0 where usr_login='XELSYSADM';
    update usr set usr_locked=0 where usr_login='XELSYSADM';
    Commit;
```

If this doesn't help, you can try below approach, this should work for sure.

```
1.Go to the <OIM_ORACLE_HOME>/server/bin directory.
2.Open the oimadminpasswd_wls.properties file.
3.Update the following variables in the oimadminpasswd_wls.properties file.

  JAVA_HOME=/opt/oim/Middleware/jdk
  COMMON_COMPONENTS_HOME=/opt/oim/Middleware/oracle_common
  OIM_ORACLE_HOME= /opt/oim/Middleware/Oracle_IDM1
  ORACLE_SECURITY_JPS_CONFIG = /opt/oim/Middleware/user_projects/domains/idm_domain/config/fmwconfig /jps-config-jse.xml
  DOMAIN_HOME=/opt/oim/Middleware/user_projects/domains/idm_domain
  DBURL=jdbc:oracle:thin:@<database server>:1521/<OIM URL>
  DBSCHEMAUSER=DEV_OIM
  #It should be true only if there is LDAP Sync and OIM OAM integration)
  OIM_OAM_INTG_ENABLED=false 
  #Only update this attribute if you have LDAP Sync enabled and have OIM-OAM    integration
  LDAPURL= 
  #Only update this attribute if you have LDAP Sync enabled and have OIM-OAM  integration)
  LDAPADMINUSER= 
  #Only update this attribute if you have LDAP Sync enabled and have OIM-OAM integration)
  OIM_ADMIN_LDAP_DN= 

4.Run the ./oimadminpasswd_wls.sh  oimadminpasswd_wls.properties
5.Provide the correct input for each question as below

        Enter OIM DB Schema Password  :
        Enter OIM Adminstrator xelsysadm new Password: 
        Re-enter OIM Adminstrator xelsysadm new Password:

(Note:You can set the same password as earlier)
```